# Style mobile navbar using Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

So I have a navbar defined in bootstrap 3, however I would like to change the size, color, and `<li>` elements when a user visits it on a mobile or tablet browser vs a desktop. What would be the best way to go about this? I thought about using media queries but I am not sure where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Media query is a good way to fix your problem. The boostrap navbar default breakpoint seems to be at 768px. see on [coderwall](https://coderwall.com/p/wpjw4w/change-the-bootstrap-navbar-breakpoint)

```
@media (max-width: 768px) { "your modifications here" }
```

Comment: Is it okay if I have that code and just change the background color to say black and padding down to about 5px while still keeping the other values from the desktop breakpoint?

Comment: It will work if you insert your stylesheet after the boostrap stylesheet. Your styles will overwrite the bootstrap rules. Warning the article from coderwall date from Feb 28, 2014, bootsrap may change their breakpoint, you need to check that

Comment: Alright I knew about the custom stylesheets, I just didn't know if the queries would overwrite my previous `.navbar {}` styles. And thanks, I will check that for sure!

Comment: media query rules are the same as other rules, they just have a condition to perform. you're welcome

Comment: After adding it into my code it worked wonderfully. Just what I needed!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to customize this more for mobile jasny perform these plugins are very good for, I have implemented in my projects and work very well for the mobile "menu offcanvas"

[jasny bootstrap offcanvas](http://jasny.github.io/bootstrap/javascript/#offcanvas)

[image: menu offcanvas]

Comment: That actually looks good. I will use that in the future for sure! Thank you very much!

Comment: No problema amigo, enjoy :D

Answer (score 0):

My way is.. 1.- detect iphone/ipad/android with jquery, 2.- Use custom media queries to target iphone, ipad. Later test in a device because using media queries only target on desktop not in a device or smartphone resolution.

Comment: It is possible to skip detecting what device the user is using with jQuery and just doing this through media queries in a custom CSS stylesheet. Bootstrap has breakpoints defined already for phones, tablets, and desktops. But thanks for the suggestion!